# Load a C++ DLL into matlab which calls functions in another DLL

Tags: c++, dll, call

For learning purposes, I'm trying to load a DLL into MATLAB which calls functions defined in another DLL. I'm new to all of this, and haven't yet been able to figure out how I would go about doing this, and nor have I managed to find any relevant resources.

I wrote a small DLL in C++ which goes something like this:

```
//example_dll.h
#ifndef EXAMPLE_DLL_H
#define EXAMPLE_DLL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef BUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

int EXAMPLE_DLL Double(int x);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // EXAMPLE_DLL_H
```

and the source file:

```
//example_dll.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example_dll.h"

int Double(int x)
{
        return 2 * x;
}
```

This I built using MinGW w64 and loaded into matlab using `loadlibrary('example_dll')` without any problems.

I now want to define the function

```
int Double(int x)
{
        return 2 * x;
}
```

In another DLL, (let's call it DLL2) and to call that function from my example_dll.
What would be the easiest way to do it?

I would appreciate a short example code (preferably for run-time dynamic linking, and without the use of module definition (.def) files) or a link to a relevant resource on the interwebs.
Thanks!

**SOLUTION TO SIMPLE EXAMPLE:**

I think I got the solution. It seems to be working anyway.

I created a DLL named `interface_DLL` which I loaded into MATLAB and from which I called my function in `example_dll`

here it is:

```
//interface_dll.h
#ifndef INTERFACE_DLL_H
#define INTERFACE_DLL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef BUILDING_INTERFACE_DLL
#define INTERFACE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define INTERFACE_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


int INTERFACE_DLL Quadruple(int x);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // INTERFACE_DLL_H
```

and the source file:

```
//interface_dll.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "interface_dll.h"
#include "example_dll.h"

int Quadruple(int x)
{
    /* get handle to dll */ 
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\uidr0605\\Documents\\ExampleDLL\\example_dll.dll"); 

    /* get pointer to the function in the dll*/
    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hGetProcIDDLL),"Double");

    /*
    Define the Function in the DLL for reuse. This is just prototyping the dll's function.
    A mock of it. Use "stdcall" for maximum compatibility.
    */
    typedef int (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(int);

    pICFUNC Double;
    Double = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);

    /* The actual call to the function contained in the dll */
    int intMyReturnVal = Double(x);
    intMyReturnVal = Double(intMyReturnVal);

    /* Release the Dll */
    FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);

    /* The return val from the dll */
    return intMyReturnVal; 
}
```

I load it from MATLAB as follows:

```
%loadDLL.m
path = 'C:\Path\to\DLL\';
addpath(path);
loadlibrary('interface_dll')
i = 2;
x = calllib('interface_dll', 'Quadruple', i)
```

The reason I'm going through this process is that [the MATLAB shared library interface supports C library routines only and not C++ classes.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-shared-library-support.html)

My idea of a workaround is to use an intermediate DLL to act as an interface between MATLAB and the DLL who's classes I intend to access.
Is there a better way of doing this?

**FURTHER QUESTIONS:**

Can anyone please explain the significance of the line `typedef int (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(int);` as applied here?
What would I have to add or what changes would I have to make if I wanted to call a function in a class in `example_dll`?

EDIT: I added the following code to the example_dll header file:

```
class EXAMPLE_DLL MyClass
{
public: 
        int add2(int);
};


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


MyClass EXAMPLE_DLL *createInstance(){
        return new MyClass();
}

void EXAMPLE_DLL destroyInstance(MyClass *ptrMyClass){
        delete ptrMyClass;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Further question 1**

The following definition

```
typedef int (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(int);
```

defines a new type pICFUNC which is a pointer to a function which takes an int and returns an int. Also, the function must be called according to the __stdcall calling convention, which specifies how arguments must be passed and how to retrieve the return value.
This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef#Using_typedef_with_function_pointers) explains typedef with function pointers. Have a look also at the following section, *Using typedef with type casts*, since on line

```
Double = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);
```

pICFUNC is used to cast instead.

**Further question 2**

The following is a very trivial example to give an idea. If you have a class in *example_dll* called *MyClass* which has a method

```
int add(int num);
```

you could implement the following functions:

```
MyClass *createInstance(){
    return new MyClass();
}

void destroyInstance(MyClass *ptrMyClass){
    delete ptrMyClass;
}
```

These function need to be *extern "C"* and you could import them with *GetProcAddress*. Then, it would be just a matter of creating an instance, calling its methods through the pointer and eventually destroying it.

**EDIT:** Some hints for the implementation

Import the function to create the instance

```
FARPROC lpfnCreateInstance = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hGetProcIDDLL), "createInstance");
```

Declare a proper pointer type for the function (returns a MyClass*, no arguments)

```
typedef MyClass* (__stdcall * pCREATINST)();
```

Cast lpfnCreateInstance

```
pCREATINST createInstance;

createInstance = pCREATINST(lpfnCreateInstance)
```

Create your instance

```
MyClass *myInstance = creatInstance();
```

Then you don't need a wrapper for add, you can just call it from your pointer.

```
int res = myInstance->add(123);
```

You should do the same for destroyInstance, being careful with the types
Please note that I can't test this code, but it should be the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. #1 is clear now.
for #2 I added your function definitions to the example_dll header file (see EDIT in my original post).

I'm not sure how to create the instance now in interface_dll. I would appreciate it if you could edit my interface_dll source file to show how this may be done.

Comment: additional information:
For the project I eventually plan to implement this on, I only have the header and .lib file available, and thus can not make any changes in the source code. How may I call the functions contained in the classes therein from my intermediary DLL and return the results to MATLAB?

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT and give it a try following those suggestions. As for you project, I guess with .lib you mean the import library for the DLL. Unfortunately I am not aware of any method to import C++ code without using extern C wrappers.

Comment: Thank you, this helps very much.
For the project, by .lib I meant static library. I have a static library which contains classes and functions that I need to call from Matlab. What I'm doing is writing a DLL to import the static lib and write functions to call corresponding functions in the static library and return to Matlab. These functions will be wrapped in extern C.